# Grafana adds additional dashboards which I don't want

Tags: grafana

[image]

Please see picture,

I didn't add Grafana, Grafana metrics, Graphite Carbon metrics... I don't know where these dashboards are defined but I need to remove them

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the [Manage Dashboards](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/dashboard_folders/#manage-dashboards) page, select the ones you don't want and delete them.